# ListBox Background not fully Transparent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a `TabControl` which contains a `ListBox`. I have set both controls's Background to `Transparent` but there seems to be some kind of frosted effect on the ListBox:

[image]

How do I get rid of this effect? Other controls in the TabControl have no issues when I set their background to Transparent, only ListBox.

**EDIT:**

I found the problem. The problem is not with ListBox, but rather SurfaceListBox. Details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5a006b6-f0a5-43fb-aff8-1d840e8ea52b/surfacelistbox-light-background-cannot-get-rid-of-it?forum=surfaceappdevelopment).

For solution, add this to the resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxBackgroundBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: you may use blend to see the style of listbox and find out which control cause this.

Comment: Post a simple code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Is that a ListBox item showing the frost? It's going to be something stuffed into the Style Template somewhere, you'll just have to find what it is exactly.

Comment: My bad, the problem is with `SurfaceListBox` and not `ListBox`. Updated with the solution.